# Trimming the start of a video generates some negative presentation timestamps

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Here is my command to trim the start of a video:

`ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:02 -i inputFile.mp4 -movflags use_metadata_tags -map_metadata 0 -c copy outputFile.mp4`

I've discovered that for some videos, some of the frame presentation timestamps become negative although the original videos had none. I've used this ffprobe command to check the pts_time values:

`ffprobe outputFile.mp4 -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time -of json`

How can I improve my Ffmpeg command to not produce negative timestamps? The playback is choppy and weird for these kind of videos.

Comment: Without re-encoding (using `-c copy`): Make sure that the first frame in which you are cutting the video is a **key-frame**. When cutting at a random position, all the frames from the nearest keyframe (before the frame) to the first output frame are going to have negative timestamps. In case there are still issues, re-encode the video. The output video stream must begin with a keyframe...

Comment: @Rotem Isn't there a command to tell ffmpeg to cut at the closest key-frame for the -ss value ? Or how can I find the closest key-frame otherwise? I want to avoid re-encoding as it takes a long time in my particular situation.

Comment: @Rotem I made some progress using ffprobe and fetching the key frames. I want to look for the closest key frame to the -ss value and use that as the -ss value. But what time value should I look at? pts_time, pkt_dts_time etc?

Comment: It supposed to be `pts_time`. I didn't test it with input file that include both video and audio streams. For testing you may start with synthetic video that has frame numbers and fixed GOP size: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 10 -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=500 -vf setpts=N/10/TB -c:v libx264 -g 50 -pix_fmt yuv420p inputFile.mp4`